# Why did my VB.NET app solution break when I moved from VS2013 on Win8.1 to VS2015 on Win10?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

My solution worked fine under Win8.1 using VS2013. Then I did a clean install of Win10. I ran the msi that was created back on XP some time ago, and it installed my VB app after asking for a .NET3 version. But then I started up VS2015 for the first time and loaded my VB app's solution. I get errors like this: BC30002 Type 'Excel.Workbook' is not defined.

I looked in Control Panel's Programs and Features and only see .NET 4.5 and 4.6 items (nothing for .NET 3).

My solution includes references to Microsoft.Office.Core and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You may need to reinstall the Office Interop Assemblies.

Comment: @Cory, thank for the tip. I googled around for Office Interop Assemblies and found some comments about .NET Programmability.  But apparently since I installed Office 2010 for Home and Student, I don't get the  .NET Programmability Support feature that includes the Office Interop Assemplies. I was using Office 2000 back when I last built this VB project. I still have those CDs but won't be able to get to them until Sept.

Comment: You can download them separately: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Comment: I just did that running o2010pia.msi, but nothing showed up in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office" where I think they should live. Possibly the installation code is not recognizing VS2015.

Comment: Could be, did anything show up in the GAC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85361/discussion-between-martinduo-and-c).

Comment: Run > C:\Windows\assembly and then look for the Microsoft.Interop entries. Also just try running your app again.

Comment: I found C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and ran the app again in VS2015; still same problem. Another reference I found said GAC moved to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly, where there is no Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel entry. Thanks for your help. I'll wait to try to Office 2000 CDs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going back to Control Panel/Programs and Features, selecting Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, clicking Uninstall or change a program. Then when the VS2015 installer opened, I selected Modify, then All (every installation option) and installed VS again. That solved the above problem.

But now I have a new error: BC30002 Type 'ExcelLateBind is not defined. How do I fix this?